# Computing $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(x)}{x^2 + x + 2} \, dx$

Tags: complex-analysis

I wish to compute
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(x)}{x^2 + x + 2} \, dx$$

The singularities are $\pm \frac{\sqrt{7}}{2}i  - \frac{1}{2}$

I then make a half-circle contour $C = \{Re^{it}, t \in [0,\pi], R \in [0,\infty) \}$

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(x)}{((x - (-\frac{\sqrt{7}i}{2} - \frac{1}{2}))(x - (\frac{\sqrt{7}i}{2} - \frac{1}{2}))} dx = \int_{C} \frac{\cos(x)}{((x - (-\frac{\sqrt{7}i}{2} - \frac{1}{2}))(x - (\frac{\sqrt{7}i}{2} - \frac{1}{2}))} dx$$

Is this correct so far?

Then we can apply Cauchy Integral Formula yes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you need to be more careful here: $\cos{z}$ does not decay on the curved arc, so you will be unable to calculate the integral by taking the radius to infinity. Instead, you'll want to look at the real part of
$$ f(z) = \frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+z+2}. $$
Clearly for $z=x$ real this is just
$$ \frac{\cos{x}}{x^2+x+2}, $$
and [Jordan's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_lemma) shows that the integral of $f(z)$ over the curved arc of your semicircle tends to zero. *Now* you can use the Cauchy integral formula on $f(z)$ on your semicircle to work with something you can calculate.

Comment: Mmm, I've not used Jordan's Lemma before. So do we just compute $\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\cos(x)}{x^2 + x + 2}$? I'm afraid I don't follow

Comment: You need Jordan's lemma for this way. There are 2 other ways: you can take a rectangular contour with one side the real axis and show that the other sides' integrals tend to zero, or you can transform the real axis to the boundary of the unit circle with a Möbius transformation substitution in the integral and then use the CIF on the circle.

Comment: Oh that sounds a lot more complicated. Could you explain Jordan's Lemma further?

Comment: The point of Jordan's lemma is that the part of the integral over the semicircular arc tends to zero as its radius increases. Then the integral over the real axis is equal to the sum of the residues in the upper half-plane.

Comment: Your integral is essentially of the same type as this example on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_contour_integration#Example_.28II.29_.E2.80.93_Cauchy_distribution

Comment: Okay, so then that means our integral would be equal to $2\pi i (Res(f(z)e^{iz}), \frac{\sqrt{7}i}{2} - \frac{1}{2})$ right? Though, computing that residue i'm not too sure about because of that $e^{iz}$

Comment: My $f(z)$ already includes the $e^{iz}$. $(z-a)f(z)$, with $a = -1/2+i\sqrt{7}/2$, is analytic in the upper half-plane, so you can just take the limit as $z \to a$. If you have further trouble, I suggest you ask a new question and present your working so far: this is getting a bit long for comments.

Answer (score 4):

We have $x^2+x+2 = (x+a)(x+b)$, where $a+b=1$ and $ab=2$. Hence, we have
$$\dfrac{\cos(x)}{x^2+x+2} = \dfrac{\cos(x)}{(x+a)(x+b)} = \dfrac1{b-a}\left(\dfrac{\cos(x)}{x+a} - \dfrac{\cos(x)}{x+b}\right)$$
Our integral is of the form
$$I = \dfrac1{b-a}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{\cos(x)}{x+a} - \dfrac{\cos(x)}{x+b}\right)dx = \dfrac{F(a) - F(b)}{b-a}$$
where $F(y) = \displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{\cos(x)}{x+y}dx$. We have
$$F(y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{\cos(t-y)}t dt = \cos(y)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{\cos(t)}tdt + \sin(y)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{\sin(t)}tdt$$
Note that the principal value of $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{\cos(t)}tdt$ is zero, since the integrand is odd. This gives us
$$F(y) = \sin(y) \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{\sin(t)}tdt = \pi \sin(y)$$
Hence, we have
$$I = \pi \cdot \dfrac{\sin(a)-\sin(b)}{b-a}$$

Answer (score 0):

I break the integral up into two terms.
$$  \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x)\,\cos{(\theta)}
=
\frac{1}{2}
\underbrace{\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x)\,e^{+\theta}}_{I_1}
+
\frac{1}{2}
\underbrace{\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x)\,e^{-\theta }}_{I_2}
,\tag{Eq. 0}$$

In Part 1, under fair use, I liberally lift from [1] to solve $I_1$. In Part 2, I paraphrase what is in Part 1 to solve $I_2$. The result is that
$$\boxed{  \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\cos{(\theta)}\,d\theta}{\left(x + \frac{1 + i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right)\,\left(x + \frac{1 - i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right) }  
= \frac{1}{2}\, 2\,\pi {    \sqrt{7}  }+  \frac{1}{2}\, 2\,\pi {    \sqrt{7}  }=    2\,\pi {    \sqrt{7}  }.}$$

**Part 1**

Consider the definite integrals
$$I_1 = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x)e^{+i\theta},\tag{Eq. 1}$$
where
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\left(x + \frac{1 + i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right)\,\left(x + \frac{1 - i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right) }. $$
This is a Fourier transform. I note that $f(z)$ is analytic except for two poles and $\lim_{|z|\to\infty}f(z) 
 = 0$ for $0\leq \text{arg}\left( z\right) \leq \pi.$
\begin{align}
\lim_{|z|\to\infty}f(z) 
&=
\lim_{|z|\to\infty}\frac{1}{\left(z + \frac{1 + i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right)\,\left(z + \frac{1 - i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right) }
\\
&=
\lim_{R\to\infty}\frac{1}{\left(R\,e^{i\theta}  + \rho\,e^{-i\phi}\right)\,\left(R\,e^{i\theta} + \rho\,e^{+i\phi} \right) }
\\
&=
\lim_{R\to\infty}\frac{1}{\left(R\,e^{i\theta}   \right)\,\left(R\,e^{i\theta}   \right) }
\\
&=
0 \qquad \tag{Eq. 2}
\end{align}

I employ a piecewise contour. The first piece:
$z : [ 0 , \pi ] \to C_1 $  is the parametrization of the curve $C_1$ that assigns to every $\theta$ in the domain the complex value $$
z(\theta) =
R\,e^{i\,\theta} 
. $$
The second piece:
$x : [ -1 , 1 ] \to C_2 $  is the parametrization of the curve $C_2$ that assigns to every $\rho$ in the domain the complex value $$
x(\rho) =
R\,\rho  
. $$

The application of the calculus of residues requires extra work to show that the integral over the (infinte) semicircle, $I_R$, goes to zero. This integral becomes
\begin{align}
I_R 
&= 
\int_0^\pi \frac{1}{\left(R\,e^{i\theta} + \frac{1 + i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right)\,\left(R\,e^{i\theta} + \frac{1 - i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right) }
e^{iR\,e^{i\,\theta} } \underbrace{\left[i\,R\,e^{i\theta}\,d\theta\right]}_{dz}
\\
&= 
\int_0^\pi \frac{1}{\left(R\,e^{i\theta} + \frac{1 + i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right)\,\left(R\,e^{i\theta} + \frac{1 - i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right) }
e^{i\,R\,  \cos{\theta} - R\,  \sin{\theta} }  i\,R\,e^{i\theta}\,d\theta 
\end{align}
Let $R$ be so large that $\left|f(z)\right| = \left|\frac{1}{\left(R\,e^{i\theta} + \frac{1 + i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right)\,\left(R\,e^{i\theta} + \frac{1 - i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right) }\right|<\epsilon$. Then,
\begin{align}
\left|I_R\right| 
&< 
\left|\epsilon\,R\,\int_0^\pi  
e^{i\,R\,  \cos{\theta} - R\,  \sin{\theta} }  i\,e^{i\theta}\,d\theta \right|
\\
&< 
\epsilon\,R\,\int_0^\pi  
\left|
e^{i\,R\,  \cos{\theta} - R\,  \sin{\theta} }  i\,e^{i\theta}\,d\theta \right|
\\
&< 
\epsilon\,R\,\int_0^\pi  
e^{  - R\,  \sin{\theta} }   \,d\theta
\\
&< 
2\,\epsilon\,R\,\int_0^{\pi/2}  
e^{  - R\,  \sin{\theta} }   \,d\theta.
\end{align}
In the range [0,\pi/2]
$$\frac{2}{\pi}\leq \sin\theta.$$
Therefore,
\begin{align}
\left|I_R\right| 
&< 
\left|\epsilon\,R\,\int_0^\pi  
e^{i\,R\,  \cos{\theta} - R\,  \sin{\theta} }  i\,e^{i\theta}\,d\theta \right|
\\
&< 
\epsilon\,R\,\int_0^\pi  
\left|
e^{i\,R\,  \cos{\theta} - R\,  \sin{\theta} }  i\,e^{i\theta}\,d\theta \right|
\\
&< 
\epsilon\,R\,\int_0^\pi  
e^{  - R\,  \sin{\theta} }   \,d\theta
\\
&< 
2\,\epsilon\,R\,\int_0^{\pi/2}  
e^{  - R\,  \frac{2\,\theta}{\pi}  }   \,d\theta.
\end{align}
Now, integrating by inspection, we obtain
$$|I_R| \leq 2\,\epsilon\,R\frac{1- e^{-R}}{2R/pi}.$$
Finally
$$\lim_{R\to\infty}|I_R| \leq  \epsilon\, \pi .$$
From Eq. 2, $\epsilon\to 0$ as $R\to\infty$ and
$$\lim_{R\to\infty}|I_R| \leq 0 .$$

This result is called Jordan's lemma. With it we are prepared to tackle our Fourier integral given in Eq. 1. Using the piecewise contour, we have
$$I_1 = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\left(x + \frac{1 + i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right)\,\left(x + \frac{1 - i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right) }\,e^{+i\theta} +\lim_{R\to\infty}|I_R|  = 2\,\pi\,i\sum \text{residues (upper half plane)} .$$
As the integral over the semicircle $I_R$  vanishes as $R\to\infty$,
$$I_1 = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\left(x + \frac{1 + i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right)\,\left(x + \frac{1 - i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right) }\,e^{+i\theta}    = 2\,\pi\,i\sum \text{residues (upper half plane)} .$$

Now, by partial-fraction expansion,
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\left(x + \frac{1 + i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right)\,\left(x + \frac{1 - i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right) }
=
\frac{k_1}{\left(x + \frac{1 + i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right)  }
+
\frac{k_2}{ \left(x + \frac{1 - i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right) }
\\
=
\frac{k_1\,\left(x + \frac{1 - i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right)}{\left(x + \frac{1 + i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right)\left(x + \frac{1 - i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right)  }
+
\frac{k_2\,\left(x + \frac{1 + i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right)}{\left(x + \frac{1 + i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right) \left(x + \frac{1 - i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right) }
\\
=
\frac{k_1\,\left(x + \frac{1 - i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right)
+ k_2\,\left(x + \frac{1 + i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right)
}{\left(x + \frac{1 + i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right)\left(x + \frac{1 - i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right)  }
\\
= 
k_1\,\frac{\left(x + \frac{1 - i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right)
-\left(x + \frac{1 + i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right)
}{\left(x + \frac{1 + i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right)\left(x + \frac{1 - i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right)  }
\\
=
k_1\,\frac{\left(  \frac{  - i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right)
-\left(  \frac{  + i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right)
}{\left(x + \frac{1 + i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right)\left(x + \frac{1 - i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right)  }
\\
=
k_1\,\frac{\left(    - i\,\sqrt{7} \right)
}{\left(x + \frac{1 + i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right)\left(x + \frac{1 - i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right)  }
\\
=
\frac{1}{\left(    - i\,\sqrt{7} \right)} \,\frac{\left(    - i\,\sqrt{7} \right)
}{\left(x + \frac{1 + i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right)\left(x + \frac{1 - i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right)  }
\end{align}
In other words,
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\left(x + \frac{1 + i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right)\,\left(x + \frac{1 - i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right) }
=
\frac{+\frac{i}{  \sqrt{7}  }}{\left(x + \frac{1 + i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right)  }
+
\frac{-\frac{i}{    \sqrt{7}  }}{ \left(x + \frac{1 - i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right) }.
\end{align}
So, I find that the there is a single isolated singularity in the upper half plane. The sum of one enclosed residues of $f(z)$ is
$$-\frac{i}{    \sqrt{7}  }.$$
Then,
$$I_1 = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\left(x + \frac{1 + i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right)\,\left(x + \frac{1 - i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right) }\,e^{+i\theta}    =  2\,\pi {    \sqrt{7}  } .$$

**Part 2**

Consider the definite integrals
$$I_2 = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x)e^{-i\theta},\tag{Eq. 3}$$
where
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\left(x + \frac{1 + i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right)\,\left(x + \frac{1 - i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right) }. $$

I employ a piecewise contour. The first piece:
$z : [ \pi , 2\pi ] \to C_3 $  is the parametrization of the curve $C_3$ that assigns to every $\theta$ in the domain the complex value $$
z(\theta) =
R\,e^{i\,\theta} 
. $$
The second piece:
$x : [ -1 , 1 ] \to C_4 $  is the parametrization of the curve $C_4$ that assigns to every $\rho$ in the domain the complex value $$
x(\rho) =
-R\,\rho  
. $$

The application of the calculus of residues requires extra work to show that the integral over the (infinite) semicircle, $I_R$, goes to zero. This integral becomes
\begin{align}
I_{R_2} 
&=  
\int_\pi^{2\pi} \frac{1}{\left(R\,e^{i\theta} + \frac{1 + i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right)\,\left(R\,e^{i\theta} + \frac{1 - i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right) }
e^{iR\,e^{-i\,\theta} } \underbrace{\left[i\,R\,e^{i\theta}\,d\theta\right]}_{dz}
\\
&= 
\int_\pi^{2\pi} \frac{1}{\left(R\,e^{i\theta} + \frac{1 + i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right)\,\left(R\,e^{i\theta} + \frac{1 - i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right) }
e^{iR\,    \cos{(\theta)} +  R   \sin { \theta} }   i\,R\,e^{i\theta}\,d\theta 
\end{align}
Let $R$ be so large that $\left|f(z)\right| = \left|\frac{1}{\left(R\,e^{i\theta} + \frac{1 + i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right)\,\left(R\,e^{i\theta} + \frac{1 - i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right) }\right|<\epsilon$. Then,
\begin{align}
\left|I_{R_2} \right| 
&< 
\left|\epsilon\,R\,\int_0^\pi  
e^{i\,R\,  \cos{\theta} + R\,  \sin{\theta} }  i\,e^{i\theta}\,d\theta \right|
\\
&< 
\epsilon\,R\,\int_0^\pi  
\left|
e^{i\,R\,  \cos{\theta} + R\,  \sin{\theta} }  i\,e^{i\theta}\,d\theta \right|
\\
&< 
\epsilon\,R\,\int_\pi^{2\pi}  
e^{  + R\,  \sin{\theta} }   \,d\theta
\\
&< 
2\,\epsilon\,R\,\int_\pi^{3 \pi/2}  
e^{   R\,  \sin{\theta} }   \,d\theta.
\\
&< 
2\,\epsilon\,R\,\int_\pi^{3 \pi/2}  
e^{   R\,  \sin{\theta} }   \,d\theta.
\end{align}
Let $\phi = \theta - \pi\qquad $
\begin{align}
\left|I_{R_2} \right| 
&< 
2\,\epsilon\,R\,\int_0^{  \pi/2}  
e^{   R\,  \sin{( \phi + \pi   )} }   \,d\phi.
\\
&< 
2\,\epsilon\,R\,\int_0^{  \pi/2}  
e^{ -  R\,  \sin{( \phi     )} }   \,d\phi.
\end{align}
Thus, as before,
$$\lim_{R\to\infty}|I_{R_2} | \leq 0 .$$

I am prepared to tackle our Fourier integral given in Eq. 3. Using the piecewise contour, we have
$$I_2 = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\left(x + \frac{1 + i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right)\,\left(x + \frac{1 - i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right) }\,e^{-i\theta} -\lim_{R\to\infty}|I_{R_2} |  = -2\,\pi\,i\sum \text{residues (upper half plane)} .$$
As the integral over the semicircle, $I_{R_2} $,  vanishes as $R\to\infty$,
$$I_2 = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\left(x + \frac{1 + i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right)\,\left(x + \frac{1 - i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right) }\,e^{+i\theta}    = -2\,\pi\,i\sum \text{residues (lower half plane)} .$$

Now, by partial-fraction expansion,
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\left(x + \frac{1 + i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right)\,\left(x + \frac{1 - i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right) }
=
\frac{+\frac{i}{  \sqrt{7}  }}{\left(x + \frac{1 + i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right)  }
+
\frac{-\frac{i}{    \sqrt{7}  }}{ \left(x + \frac{1 - i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right) }.
\end{align}
So, I find that the there is a single isolated singularity in the lower half plane. The sum of one enclosed residues of $f(z)$ is
$$\frac{i}{    \sqrt{7}  }.$$
Then,
$$I_2 = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\left(x + \frac{1 + i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right)\,\left(x + \frac{1 - i\,\sqrt{7}}{2}\right) }\,e^{-i\theta}    = 2\,\pi {    \sqrt{7}  } .$$

[1] Arfken and Weber, Mathematical Methods for Physicists